# Where are JWT tokens stored on the server and other related questions

Tags: security, jwt

As the title suggests, where are JWT tokens stored on the server side? in database or in memeory? I understand the implementation can vary due to different requirements, but just in general where would you store it?

If I want to provide a very basic token authentication server, meaning upon receiving a username and password via a POST request, I would like to return a token. In this case, how is a token generated with a very basic algorithm work differently than a jwt token?

With a token generated by a simple algorithm:

1. it does not contain payload
2. its value is not computed based on the username and password, thus it cannot be rehashed back to anything meaningful

In this case, is there still value to use JWT?

Comment: I'd really like to know where JWT tokens are stored on the server. @Cheng Did you find the answer by now?

Comment: @Cheng what about now?

Comment: @Abhi read the last answer scroll down

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to store token on server side.
You should store a private key ( any string of your choice)at server preferably as environment variable.The jsonwebtoken provided method use this private key to generate a token to pass to client.
Client has to store this token at client side so that it can pass this token to subsequent request to server in header.
Server would extract the token value from header and validate it using private key by calling a method of jsonwebtoken.If token is not modified by any means then validate will succeed.

Comment: I have a scenario in mind. Lets say user logged in to two diff system and s/he change password from one system then it should be logged out from another system.How do I invalidate that another token? If we don't store it on server.

Comment: if password is changed on one system while a further request is made from another system where token is stored, then once the old token is received by the server it will validate the token with the present information at server side ( new password+ secret key + others information used previously). Since due to new password new token would not remain same and so validation would fail.

Comment: Which means we need to fetch new password from db every time request arrive. Which is not a good practice I believe. The primary purpose of JWT is that they are self validated and doesn't require server to store anything.

Comment: It is all about the requirement and need, if the requirement is to invalidate previously issued tokens then tokens need to be mapped to a user id. When a password change action happens you may add a piece of code to invalidate all previous tokens (in fact the current token too after the password update, to enforce the user to login with new credentials).

Answer (score 7):

client needs to store it, on server storage is not required.

JWT have all the claims in itself and is signed by the server as well. On receipt, server checks for the signature and reads the claims. It does not match it against a stored value. That is the whole point of using JWT against access tokens.

Look at how a JWT is structured.

Comment: I have a scenario in mind. Lets say user logged in to two diff system and s/he change password from one system then it should be logged out from another system.How do I invalidate that another token?

Comment: @RashminJaviya that's why you should use it with an expiry time so when the frontend gets 401 and try to get a new token using a refresh token let's say he will get redirected to the login page since that refresh token shouldn't be valid(of course you have some handling to do in the backend when changing your password). Relating only on the JWT to secure your APIs ain't enough.

Comment: @MichelElHajj Yeah but there will be time gap of exactly the validity of token. it is not immediate. If you try google/fb they log you out immediately from all sessions. this is possible but then server has to store all jwt token in db/memory associated with userid but the whole purpose of jwt is to not store them on server side.

Comment: @RashminJaviya if you combine isRevoked with blacklistTokens notations with a couple of coding lines on log out you can achieve this

Comment: @MichelElHajj Thanks. I will try and check.

Answer (score 6):

Jwt token is not required to be stored but the "secret-key" needs to be stored.
The structure of jwt is header.payload.signature where signature is generated as below by the server :

```
signature = HS256(base64Header + '.' + base64Payload, 'mysecret')
```

So in essense:
1.header.payload.signature is sent to client on first sign in

2.client return back header.payload.signature in subsequent api call
3.server decodes it for verification as below:
    base64Header, base64Payload, signature = token.split('.')

```
header = base64Decode(base64Header)  
payload = base64Decode(base64Payload)

serverComputedSignature = HS256(base64Header + '.' + base64Payload, 
'mysecret')

if serverComputedSignature != signature:  
 print('FAILED')
```

Answer (score 4):

A token is a generic term. JWT defines the structure of a token which contains the below three parts.

```
1. header
2. payload
3. signature
```

Storing JWT or any other format of token is driven by the business need.
If the content of the JWT has to be used/validated for any reason then it can be stored in a DB or any other storage.
If the need is to validate the signature then there is no reason to store the issued JWT.

Answer (score 0):

in client side, Use cookies to store JWT tokens – always secure, always httpOnly, and with the proper same site flag.
while in server side we don't need to store token on server side. we need to store private key which we get in signature of jwt should be stored in  environment variable.